# Facebook chat using graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, chat

I'm using graph API in order to use Facebook chat.
I'm using the http://restfb.com/ framework.
The issue is that with the following code I can read all conversations and messages.

```
public void initClient()
    {

        m_facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(MY_ACCESS_TOKEN, MY_APP_SECRET);
    }
public void readPage()
    {
        Page page = m_facebookClient.fetchObject("352179081632935", Page.class);
        System.out.println("Page likes = " + page.getLikes());


        Connection<Conversation> conversations = m_facebookClient.fetchConnection("me/conversations", Conversation.class);

    for(List<Conversation> conversationPage : conversations) {
        for(Conversation conversation : conversationPage) {
            System.out.println(conversation);
            System.out.println(conversation.getUnreadCount());

            Message lastMessage = null;
            for (Message message : conversation.getMessages())
            {
                System.out.println("Message text = " + message.getMessage());
                System.out.println("Message unread = " + message.getUnread());
                System.out.println("Message from = " + message.getFrom().getName());
                System.out.println("Message to = " + message.getTo().get(0).getName());
                System.out.println("Message unseen = " + message.getUnseen());
                lastMessage = message;
            }
        }    
    }
```

I would like to know how to send reply messages or new messages using this framework or Graph API?

Thank you,
Moshe

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is no `me/conversations` endpoint for users. Conversations are only available for Pages so it would be `/{page-id}/conversations`: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/conversations

The Facebook docs explain in detail how it works, including some example code. I suggest using one of the official SDKs instead (JS SDK, PHP SDK, ...).

The Chat API (which is what you would want to use) is deprecated: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/

Meaning, it is not possible anymore to use the Facebook chat in your App.

Comment: me/conversations does exist, It works if the token is a page token.

Answer (score 0):

I found the way yo solve it by replying based on the conversation id.

For example:

```
m_facebookClient.publish("t_mid.1420120490471:36257b35667389d257/messages", FacebookType.class, Parameter.with("message", "RestFB test"));
```

t_mid.1420120490471:36257b35667389d257 - is the conversation id

Comment: yeah, as i said, that´s explained very well in the facebook docs. of course you reply to a specific conversation id. if you take a look at the link i posted, this is one of the infos in there: "You can't publish using this edge, you can send replies via the API by using the /{conversation-id}/messages edge."

Comment: Does this solution still work? t_mid.1420120490471:36257b35667389d257  does not look like a conversation id. Can you send me a link where are these "well explained facebook docs"?